# compass query containing / (slash)

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, compass-lucene

I am using compass based indexing on my project. My annotation based configuration for the field 'name' is :

```
@SearchableProperty(name="name")
@SearchableMetaData(name="ordering_name", index=Index.NOT_ANALYZED)
private String name;
```

Now following values are store for 'name' field :

```
1. Temp 0 New n/a
2. e/f search
3. c/d search
```

Now the search result with difference scenarios is as follows :

```
1. 'c/d' -> +(+alias:TempClass +(c/d*)) +(alias:TempClass) -> 1 record found
2. 'n/a' -> +(+alias:TempClass +(n/a*)) +(alias:TempClass) -> 0 record found
3. 'search' -> +(+alias:TempClass +(search*)) +(alias:TempClass) -> 2 records found
```

So when I am trying to search 'n/a', it should search the first record with value 'Temp 0 New n/a'.

Any help would be highly appreciated !!!

Comment: I see `(n/a*)` where it should be `(*n/a)`.

Comment: @Joop... plz check the update in the question

Comment: Sorry, another (too) wild guess then: "n/a" might not be the value, but the toString of a part saying "not/available". Maybe try searching for "/a".

Comment: Would try "New n/a" as value too. Maybe the index is limited to 10 chars. _This is wild guessing._

Comment: Since we already started wild guessing... Do you know what analyzer is being used? maybe your term is being cut to n a and a being a stop word of the standard analyzer might not yield results?

Comment: @csupning : any alternate to skip the stopword 'a' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point your query analysis doesn't match with your Document analysis.

Most likely you are internally using Lucene's [StandardAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) on the query parsing but not at index time, as detonated by:

```
@SearchableMetaData(name="ordering_name", index=Index.NOT_ANALYZED))
```

The [StandardTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html) used inside this analyzer considers the character `/` as a word boundary (such as space would be), producing the tokens `n` and `a`. Later on, the token `a` is removed by a [StopFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopFilter.html).

The following code is an example for this explanation (the input is `"c/d e/f n/a"`):

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("CONTENT", new StringReader("c/d e/f n/a"));
CharTermAttribute term = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
PositionIncrementAttribute position = tokenStream.getAttribute(PositionIncrementAttribute.class);
int pos = 0;
while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
    String termStr = term.toString();
    int incr = position.getPositionIncrement();
    if (incr == 0 ) {
        System.out.print(" [" + termStr + "]");
    } else {
        pos += incr;
        System.out.println(" " + pos + ": [" + termStr +"]");
    }
}
```

You'll see the following extracted tokens:

```
 1: [c]
 2: [d]
 3: [e]
 4: [f]
 5: [n]
```

Notice that the expected position 6: with token `a` is missing. As you can see, Lucene's [QueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html) also performs this tokenization:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "content", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
System.out.println(parser.parse("+n/a*"));
```

The output is:

```
+content:n
```

EDIT: The solution would be to use [WhitespaceAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html), and set the field to ANALYZED. The following code is a proof of concept under Lucene:

```
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(new RAMDirectory(), new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36)));
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("content","Temp 0 New n/a", Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED));
writer.addDocument(doc);
writer.commit();
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(writer, true);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "content", new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
TopDocs docs = searcher.search(parser.parse("+n/a"), 10);
System.out.println(docs.totalHits);
writer.close();
```

The output is: `1`.

Comment: now i understood what exactly is happening in my app because of the StandardAnalyzer. Is there any way that we can override the stopwords (i need to remove 'a' from stopword list) ? Or any other suggestion to resolve this issue would be highly appreciated....

Comment: I've just edited the answer and gave a possible solution. I hope it helps!